# how to call super with before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Almost all of my controller actions in a rails app, have the first line of this

```
@result = super
```

So, I decided to have this declaration in a before_filter but somehow this does not work. I either get nothing rendered or

```
Filter chain halted as :result rendered or redirected
```

So basically, how can i call super for every action in a controller?

cheers.

update:

This controller lives in a mountable engine and its duty is to manipulate default api's result and render then again.

here is is the basic structure

```
class Api::Custom::PlayersController < Api::V1::PlayersController
 before_filter :result
 def result
   @result = super
 end

 def func1
  @result.first
 end
 def func2
  ...
```

update 2:

I think, now i know now the exact problem. Here is the inheritance structure of my controllers

```
-ApiBaseContoller
 -ApiPlayersController
  -Api::Custom::PlayersController
```

Even though I call before_filter method at the last controller, It triggers it at the grandparent class "ApiBaseContoller" and in that controller, it will not know what super is.

I wonder if there is any before_filter equivalent that can be triggered between ApiPlayersController and Api::Custom::PlayersController.

```
-ApiBaseContoller
 -ApiPlayersController
   before_filter :do_something 
  -Api::Custom::PlayersController
```

Comment: there must be other before_filter which requires @result, can you paste some of your controller code

Comment: @Salil, there is one more before_filter in this controller and i use it to stop rendering the json result from base api.

Comment: Apparently, you can't call super in a before_filter, since before filter is executed before the calling method is processed. thus, it will try to look for before_filter method's super class. and this is not what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to capture the action's output and manipulate it then you need to be using an `around_filter`, not a `before_filter`. I'm not sure whether this plays well with rails' new(ish) streaming features.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly i am trying to do. I read about around_filter and tried. no luck.
I also want to use rails' streaming feature soon for the app. can you explain as well what are your concerns about it?

Comment: Well my concern would be if the response starts to be sent before after code runs then it's too late to change it. Perhaps you could update the question to explain what you're trying to do and how around_filter failed you